# UISplitViewController master slide in only works after rotation

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working with a UISplitViewController, and the master is set to be hidden on portrait orientation. In that orientation, the app should open the master view controller with a swipe from left to right gesture.

The problem is that this is not happening unless I rotate the device. If the app starts on landscape, I change to portrait and it works properly (since one rotation was made). If the app starts already on portrait, I need do change to landscape then back.

How can I make it work since the app is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be the default behavior. Re-setting the delegate upon rotation seems to fix it.